# Not able to open PST using redemption with Exchange Mapi with CDO 1.2.1

Tags: perl, outlook-redemption, pst

On a Exchange server 2013 machine Exchange Mapi CDO 1.2.1 is installed.
I have exported the mailbox into the PST file using powershell commands.
I want to open the PST file in program using the Redemption library.
The session object is created successfully and LogOnPSTStore method is also not giving any error, but when I access the Stores.count it gives me an error. The perl code looks like below:

```
$session = Win32::OLE->CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession");
$session->LogonPstStore("sample.pst");
print $session->Stores->Count;
```

Any help on how can I read the emails from PST on above scenario is really helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is the exact error? Keep in mind that the standalone version of MAPI cannot open Unicode PST files.

Comment: Using the standalone version of MAPI, unicode PST files cannot be opened. Thanks Dmitry for pointing me in a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using the standalone version of MAPI, unicode PST files cannot be opened. Thanks Dmitry for pointing me in a right direction.